What's the canonical form for a parabolic isometry generator in the hyperboloid model for $\mathbb{H}^2$?
We consider $$\mathbb{H}^2:=\{p\in \mathbb{R}^{2,1}:q(p,p)=-1\},$$
where $\mathbb{R}^{2,1}=(\mathbb{R}^3,q)$ is the lorentzian 3-space endowed with the pseudo-metric
$$q((a,b,c),(x,y,z))= ax+by-cz.$$
The pseudometric in fact induces a riemannian metric on $\mathbb{H}^2$ and this is the hyperboloid model for the hyperbolic plane.
Now I'm interested in the isometries for this model. I am more familiar to the upper half plane (which I'm going to denote by $\mathbb{H}_+^2$), in which isometries, up to a reversing in orientation, are given by composition of Möbius transformations of the form
\begin{align*}
\rho_\theta(z)=\frac{(\cos \theta)z+\sin \theta}{-(\sin \theta)z+\cos \theta},\quad \tau_a(z)=e^az,\quad p_b(z)=z+b
\end{align*}
for any constants $\theta,a, b\in \mathbb{R}$.
Now, we have a map to change between models, namely
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{cccl}
\omega :&\mathbb{H}^{2}&\rightarrow& \mathbb{\mathbb{\mathbb{H}}}_{+}^{2}\\
&(x,y,z)&\mapsto & \left( \frac{y}{x-z},\frac{1}{z-x}\right)
\end{array},\quad \begin{array}{cccl}
\omega^{-1} :&\mathbb{H}_+^{2}&\rightarrow& \mathbb{\mathbb{\mathbb{H}}}^{2}\\
&(x,y)&\mapsto & \left( \frac{x^{2}+y^{2}-1}{2y},-\frac{x}{y},\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}+1}{2y}%
\right)
\end{array}.
\end{align*}
Then, I tried to convert isometries in the $\mathbb{H}_+^2$ model to isometries in the $\mathbb{H}^2$ one.
First, I got that $\rho_\theta$ and $\tau_a$ corresponds to $R_\theta, T_a:\mathbb{H}^2\to \mathbb{H}^2$ given by
\begin{align*}
R_\theta =
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos 2\theta & -\sin 2\theta & 0\\
\sin 2\theta & \cos \theta & 0\\
0 & 0 &1 
\end{bmatrix},\quad 
T_a = \begin{bmatrix}
\cosh a &0 & \sinh a\\
0 &1 & 0\\
\sinh a & 0 &\cosh a 
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}
Now, these "look" good for generators of the isometry group of $\mathbb{H}^2$. If we want $T_a$ to look a bit better, we can take instead
\begin{align*}
T_a = \begin{bmatrix}
1 &0 & 0\\
0 &\cosh a & \sinh a\\
0& \sinh a &\cosh a 
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}
My question is about the parabolic generator $p_b$. Doing the same process above I got $P_b:\mathbb{H}^2\to \mathbb{H}^2$ given by
\begin{align*}
P_b=\begin{bmatrix}
1-\frac{1}{2}b^{2} & -b & \frac{1}{2}b^{2} \\ 
b & 1 & -b \\ 
-\frac{1}{2}b^{2} & -b & 1+\frac{1}{2}b^{2}
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}
Now, this as I said, this is given solely by applying the transition maps between the models. It is not a huge mess, but it doesn't look as good as the generators $R_\theta$ and $T_a$ (and a bit frustrating since the parabolic Möbius generator is maybe the simplest one in $\mathbb{H}_+^2$ model).
Can we change $P_b$ to a better canonical form?

I'm not sure what you're fishing for, so here's an answer which amounts to "That looks pretty good to me", augmented by some facts about hyperbolic isometries that you don't mention.
The thing to keep in mind here is that parabolic isometries, rotations (like your $R_\theta$), and translations (like your $T_a$), all have different dynamics. A parabolic isometry, represented as a $3 \times 3$ matrix $M \in SO_+(2,1)$, must have a single eigenspace in $\mathbb R^{2,1}$, that eigenspace must be one-dimensional, that eigenspace must lie on the light cone, and its eigenvalue must be $1$. These properties are all enforced by the dynamical requirement that the parabolic isometry has a single fixed point on the circle at infinity of $\mathbb H^2$, and that fixed point is neither attracting nor repelling. Your example has eigenspace spanned by the light cone vector $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$, which seems about as simple as possible (other light cone vectors will have worse looking parabolic subgroups).
Your set of matrices $\{P_b\}$ also gives a perfectly nice representation of the parabolic subgroup of $SO_+(2,1)$ that fixes that light cone vector: the parameter map $b \mapsto \{P_b\}$ is a group isomorphism, because the $(1,2)$ entry of $P_b \cdot P_c$ is $b+c$.
So, what's not to like?

You're answer is really helpful! I tried a bit more and also realized that "it is what it is" and it can't "look" too much better (whatever that means). Your answer helped me to be even more convinced. Thank you!
